# Unable to generate a MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have a table in a MySQL database as below:

```
ID  Timestamp           State
1   2013-07-10 09:00:00 Good
1   2013-07-10 09:10:00 Good
1   2013-07-10 09:20:00 Good
1   2013-07-10 09:30:00 Bad
1   2013-07-10 09:40:00 Bad
1   2013-07-10 09:50:00 Bad
1   2013-07-10 10:00:00 Good
1   2013-07-10 10:10:00 Good
```

I want to generate a report as shown below using the above table.

```
ID  Start Timestamp         End Timestamp        Duration(in mins)  State
1   2013-07-10 09:00:00 2013-07-10 09:30:00 30          Good
1   2013-07-10 09:30:00 2013-07-10 10:00:00 30          Bad
1   2013-07-10 10:00:00 2013-07-10 10:10:00 10          Good
```

The query that I had generated is not able to showcase the switching taking place.

Comment: Do all rows have `id = 1`?

Comment: Do you have any primary keys in your table?

Comment: Are the `Timestamp` values unique? Or are they unique at least per `ID`?

Comment: No multiple IDs can come. I have not included the PK column in the sample data that I have given above. Timestamp value is not unique.

Comment: logic is not clear

Comment: The logic is to display the various states of an id along with start time and end time and duration for which the id was in that state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is using user variables. The following code will sort through the table  (first in reverse) and then through this result set (grouping and) keeping only rows that are wanted:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    MIN(time_stamp) AS start_timestamp, 
    start_ts        AS end_timestamp,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(time_stamp), start_ts)
                    AS duration_in_mins,
    MIN(state)      AS state
FROM    
  ( SELECT 
        id, time_stamp, state,
        @st_ts :=
            CASE WHEN state = @prev_state AND id = @prev_id
                     THEN @st_ts 
                 WHEN id = @prev_id THEN @prev_ts 
                     ELSE time_stamp
            END AS start_ts, 
        @prev_ts := time_stamp,
        @prev_state := state,
        @prev_id := id
    FROM sample
       CROSS JOIN
         ( SELECT 
             @prev_state := '',  @prev_ts := 0,
             @st_ts := 0,        @prev_id := 0 
         ) AS dummy 
    ORDER BY id DESC, time_stamp DESC
  ) AS tmptable 
GROUP BY 
    id, start_ts ;
```

Test at **[SQL-Fiddle-1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/593e9/41)**